# MYSQL2 Connect EconNRefused

Tags: javascript, mysql, database

I'm trying to host a discord bot but it requires MYSQL2 as I need to do some database stuff. If I run this bot on my computer, it works fine. However, if I run it on my vps this error shows up:
[image]

Does anyone know why this is the case? It works very fine on my computer. I'm really struggling to find the answer. Please let me know if you know the solution to this :) Thanks, Joony.

Comment: Do you have the database set up on you VPS? - it seems to be connecting to `::1` which is IPv6 version of localhost

Comment: I'm trying to connect from a VPS to a Database hosted on a web server so

Comment: Check your configuration file to make sure that it is connecting to the right IP address as mentioned above it is trying to connect to localhost, make sure that your port is also open to accept external connections through the firewall.

Comment: this has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem where the connection was being rejected. Found that changing the host from 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' solved the problem.

For example:

> ```
> const db = mysql.createConnection({
>   host: "localhost",
>   user: "username",
>   password: "password",
>   database: "myDatabase"
> });
> ```

became:

```
const db = mysql.createConnection({ host: "127.0.0.1", user: "username", password: "password", database: "myDatabase" });
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. I just had to go to the virtual private server I was using, then just get the direct IP and replace it with `localhost` and it worked out great. 20 hours of struggling and finally found the solution!